# How can i set the value to a Nested Property inside a main Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Im trying to set the value of a Nested object and Im getting a null object, how can I set it in the proper way?

```
new Object[]{ new Object { Name = "Name", object2 = new Object2 { Country = "country", Address= "address", Emails = "email@email.com" , PhoneNumbers =  "800-555-5555" }}
            }
```

Comment: Which one is null? What do your classes `Object` and `Object2` look like?

Comment: They are both custom classes and Im using them as a seed method in a .Net Core Api

Comment: Well your code looks like it should work, which one is null?

Comment: it was a nested property inside an Entity, I was trying to insert data on the 2 objects in the same operation, it happens that I changed to a List and it got more complicated, but it was a matter of relationship, and it was resolved, Thanks!